# Reading excel file using pyspark while preserving the date format

Tags: python, excel, date, pyspark, format

I want to read an excel file using pyspark while preserving the date format.

My excel file looks like this:

[image]

After running my code, it now looks like this:

[image]

Here is my code in pyspark:

`df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("header", "true").load('/mnt/dropzone/2022_v3.xlsx')`

As much as possible, we don't want to transform the data programmatically. Just read the data as-is.

Thanks.

Comment: if you just want to read the data as is, why are you reading it as a dateFormat and not as a string?  Your data is not modified, it represents exactly the same date. If you want that representation to be exactly like the original read it as a string.

Comment: I am reading it as string, but it's still changing the format.

Answer (score 0):

Set **inferSchema** to **True** and I hope that should work for you.

Below is the code for that.

```
sparkDF = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .option("inferSchema", True) \
    .load("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/sample.xlsx")
sparkDF.printSchema()
```

Please refer below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## There are two ways to handle this .

1. In case you want all the fields schema same as excel then
   `.option("inferSchema", True)` this option works well and solves the above mentioned issue.
2. If you want fields to be in specific datatype then this is how you can do it while reading

- Define the schema

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("date_column", DateType(), True),
    StructField("other_column1", StringType(), True),
    StructField("other_column2", StringType(), True),
    #Add more columns as needed
])
```

- Use the schema and option to read the Excel file

```py
df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
    .schema(schema) \
    .option("timestampFormat", "M/d/yyyy") \
    .load("path/to/excel/file.xlsx")
```